# Proof-of-Work Substrate Chain with Multiple Validators

Tags: transactions, consensus, offchain, https, proof-of-work

I'm working on a Proof-of-Work (POW) substrate chain. Assuming we have four validators, all of which have enabled on-chain workers (OCW), is it accurate to state that each validator's OCW fetches data from an external source?

If so, how is the data fetched by OCWs from different validators prioritized or transacted to the chain?